# OEL7 - How do I get perl-Template-Toolkit and perl-XML-LibXSLT without CPAN?

Tags: linux, perl

I want to open this thread by saying that I'm no Linux expert whatsoever.
I'm currently attempting to install otrs-5.0.10-01.noarch.rpm (otrs.com) on OEL7_x86_64 which seems to be built upon Red Hat 7 as per below:

> [root@**** ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
>
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

Their installation manual states that I should use yum to resolve dependencies as per below:

> [root@@**** ~]# yum install --nogpgcheck /var/tmp/otrs-5.0.9-01.noarch.rpm

This command will however complain about two dependencies not being fulfilled:

> Error: Package: otrs-5.0.9-01.noarch (/otrs-5.0.9-01.noarch)
>
> ```
>       Requires: perl(XML::LibXSLT)
> ```
>
> Error: Package: otrs-5.0.9-01.noarch (/otrs-5.0.9-01.noarch)
>
> ```
>       Requires: perl(Template)
> ```

I've found that I'm able to install them using CPAN, but the dependencies will still not be fulfilled as it seems that yum cannot see the modules that was installed using CPAN, hence I believe I need rpms for these packages.

I've found a PDF from Oracle that shows what packages are included in each of the distros and it seems that both perl-Template-Toolkit and perl-XML-LibXSLT should be included - see column Oracle Linux 7.

http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/enterprise-linux-indemnification-069347.pdf

But I cannot find the rpms in our repository and it is not installed on the system. If I check for all perl-modules available via our repo I cannot find either template or xlm-libxslt:

> yum whatprovides "perl(*)"

If I check the contents of the repository I can verify that they are not included in "Oracle Linux 7 (x86_64) Latest".

http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/index.html

So my question is short... how do I get these packages in rpm format so that my dependencies for OTRS can be resolved? I can see that they are included in the OEL6 Repository for arch i686 but I'm not certain whether they can be used safely in this system....

Any tips are appreciated, a hamburger and a beer for anyone willing to help!

Many thanks!

/Danny

Answer (score 1):

You may try these two binaries

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/26645953/dir/centos_7/com/perl-Template-Toolkit-2.24-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

and

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/29075984/dir/centos_7com/perl-XML-LibXSLT-1.80-4.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Or build from src rpms

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/2/search/perl-Template-Toolkit-2.24-5.el7.src.rpm

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/2/search/perl-XML-LibXSLT-1.80-4.el7.src.rpm

Comment: Many thanks for the fast answer. I just want to confirm that it is OK to use rpms that seem intended for CentOS7? Would it be most feasible to build from src rpms rather than using the centos rpms?

Comment: I guess the bottom line is that if it survives `rpm -Uvh` it is likely fine.  Of course building off source rpms is always safe but then you will need the build tools and friends installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is raising several issues:

1. "*I've found that I'm able to install them using CPAN, but the dependencies will still not be fulfilled as it seems that yum cannot see the modules that was installed using CPAN*"
2. "*how do I get these packages in rpm format so that my dependencies for OTRS can be resolved?*"

Let's get deeper.

As for 1), it seems that you **ALREADY** installed the two modules from CPAN and that, despite this, the installation of the RPM packages still fail. If this is the case (please, confirm), than you could safely "force" the installation of the RPM with a `rpm -ivh --nodeps otrs-5.0.9-01.noarch`.
Although this might sound a bit "rude", it's really "safe", as you can always rollback such an install (with a `rpm -e otrs`). I bet that if the two mentioned above where the only two packages missing, this will solve your problem;

As for 1), also, you can easily check if you succesfully installed the two packages simply asking PERL to "check" for them:
`perl -e 'use XML::LibXSLT'` and `perl -e 'use Template'`. If such both commands will succeed (they will simply run and end, without any output and, specifically, without complaining!) than they are correctly installed and recognized by PERL and, as such, by the (to be installed) otrs.

As for 2) things are slightly more complex, 'cause if your "distribution mantainers" (OEL 7) have **not** prebuilt a package for such a distribution, than you have little chances to find "official" RPMs. 
BUT... one of the beauty of open-source and RPMs (as well as DEBs or other package formats) is that you can really get some other "third-party" assembled package and "check" **HOW** it has been built and **WHAT** it contains. As you mentioned that OEL7 is based on RHEL7, than I bet that CentOS packages should be **ok** for your system. The easiest way to check:

- which files will be stored on your filesystem, and where;
- which script will be launched right before and right after the installation of the RPM

is, in my opinion, to open them with "mc" (`yum install mc`, if you don't have it already). Simply highlight the RPM and press ENTER. Then you'll have "contents". Just "click" it and you'll see which files are contained in the RPM. Back to main level (ESC, ESC, etc.) you can "click" the SCRIPTS folder, where you can see PREINSTALL, POSTINSTALL, PREUNINSTALL, POSTUNINSTALL. Press F3 and you're done.
Also, checking the properties of the RPM, you can see which is the TGZ file (the URL) that have been used to build the RPM.
With all such infos, you're ansolutely **free** to take the TGZ by yourself and start "building" your own RPM. Anyway, it's not really something that a "young sysadmin" could be successful in 10 minutes :-)

Let me close stating that I'd suggest the approach 1) as.... if you manually install the PERL modules via CPAN, you already have (slightly) messed your system so.... you cannot do more damages :-)

Comment: This is valuable! I have Veeam and can get rid of the CPAN mess I've created :) However, I would very much like to avoid using rpm -ihv for the otrs package seeing as it will output an even greater set of broken dependencies that yum seems to resolve:

bash-completion httpd perl(Archive::Zip) perl(Crypt::SSLeay) perl(Date::Format) perl(DBI) perl(IO::Socket::SSL) perl(LWP::UserAgent) perl(Net::DNS) perl(Net::LDAP) perl(Template) perl(URI) perl(XML::LibXML) perl(XML::LibXSLT) perl(XML::Parser) perl-core procmail

Not sure, but are you recommending approach 2 then? :)

Many thanks!